# What causes IE to break base tag if I don't use www?

Tags: internet-explorer, url-rewriting, radix

I am using a `<base>` tag like this, currently my website is in a directory for development purpose so

```
<base href="http://domain.com/directory/" />
```

Now my stylesheets and everything works fine, it is also fetched by IE9, but I am using `@import` in my stylesheet for importing font awesome stylesheet, but the font breaks if the URL in IE is typed as www.domain.com/directory, but works great if URL is domain.com/directory, why is that so? is the font path in font-awesome.min.css is lost?

Directory structure:

```
root
  -Directory
    -home.php
    -about.php
    --includes
        embeds.php 
            /* embeds.php is included in all pages, and has all stylesheets with path 
            <link href="stylesheets/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
            media="screen" /> */
    --stylesheets
         default.css
         font-awesome-min.css /* This is imported in default.css */
    --Fonts
      Has Font Awesome Files
```

Font Awesome Stylesheet Fonts Path

```
@font-face{
  font-family:'FontAwesome';
  src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
  src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal }
```

Only Issue with IE, no other browser

Note: If I use the below condition it works fine

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <base href="http://www.domain.com/directory/" />
<![endif]-->
```